# C: Compiler warning "return discards qualifiers from pointer target type"

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I get a compiler "warning: return discards qualifiers from pointer target type" from my function below.

```
unsigned char* getBeginning(const unsigned char * Packet)
{
                    return Packet+3;
}
```

I have researched this on SO and other places, and it appears the compiler is complaining that although I take in a const pointer, I am returning a non-const pointer.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

1) I want to let the users know that I will not change any of their data in this function, hence the const.

2) However, later functions will use the pointer returned here to make changes, so I don't want to make my return type const as well.

Is there a better way to do this where I don't get a warning? I'm still learning C.

Comment: Are you sure you need to remove the `const`? That just sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: @sircodesalot: That's a common C idiom for this case (the alternative would be to write two functions (one for `const`, one for non-`const`), or to write only a non-`const` version and let the caller cast the `const` away), cf. `strchr`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! After reading the responses it is possible I am doing this completely wrong. I was intending for the user to pass me a unsigned char *. It doesn't have to be a const unsigned char *. I figured I could use the "const" in the function definition to show that I would not be modifying the data pointed to IN THIS PARTICULAR function. So, in other words, I'm not expecting the user to pass me a const unsigned char *, I just wanted to show them I'm not going to touch the unsigned char * here. Later, the returned pointer does modify data. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C does not have an implicit conversion from const-qualified pointer types to non-const-qualified ones, so you should add an explicit one, i.e. a cast. Then the warning will go away:

```
unsigned char* getBeginning(const unsigned char * Packet)
{
                    return (unsigned char *)Packet+3;
}
```

Just beware that this function is then mildly "dangerous" as it can hide the dropping of const qualification. But it's no more dangerous than things like `strchr` in the standard library which do the same. The behavior is perfectly well-defined as long as you refrain from attempting to modify a const-qualified object via the returned pointer.

Comment: If I understand you, to modify the return of `strchr` results in undefined behavior, right?

Comment: Not _really_, it depends on the pointer passed to it, if _it_ was a `const char`, then modifying it would be risky... just don't expect that passing a string literal constant to it returns a new pointer to a modifiable array of char (no malloc + memcpy happens), but if you pass a regular `char*` to it, those memory locations stay the same, if it pointed to a `char[99]` it is safe to modify those 99 bytes

Comment: It's not the type of the pointer passed to it that matters, but the type of the object pointed to. If it's a `const char` array, or a string literal, then modification through `strchr`'s return value produces UB. If it's a `char` array that's not a string literal, then modification is valid (short of any other cause for it being undefined, like data races, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

`Packet` is declared as `const unsigned char *`.  Without an explicit cast when you add 3 you are implicitly declaring the result to be the same type.

To fix the error you must explicitly cast the return type:

```
return (unsigned char *) Packet + 3;
```